# Enable a button if all the UITextFields are filled and one of them has an Int value

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uikit

I have problem with associating the textField to my `shouldChangeCharactersIn` func, and this textField should contain Int values. First textField should contain String value, and second should contain Int value. Confirm button should be enabled only if textFields are filled with correct types. That's my app:
[image]

And code:

```swift
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   var av = ActualValues()
   var statsVC = StatsViewController()
   var closureBlock: (() -> Void)?

   @IBOutlet weak var idTextField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var idCheckButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
   @IBOutlet weak var targetsTextField: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      statsVC.allRunsFunc()
      idTextField.delegate = self
      idCheckButton.isEnabled = false
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      av.shift = 1
      allRunsFunc()
   }

   @IBAction func idCheckButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
      av.id = idTextField.text!
      av.databaseID = String(runs + 1)
      av.target = targetsTextField.text!
      closureBlock?()
      if let delegate = self.summaryButtonIsEnabledDelegate {
         delegate.toggleSummaryButton()
      }

      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   @IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
      switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
      case 0:
        av.shift = 1
      case 1:
        av.shift = 2
      case 2:
        av.shift = 3
      default:
        av.shift = 1
      }
   }

   func configureID(model: ActualValues) {
     av = model
   }

   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String, int: Int) -> Bool {
      let text = (idTextField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
      if text.isEmpty {
         idCheckButton.isEnabled = false
      } else {
         idCheckButton.isEnabled = true
      }

      return true
   }
}
```

What should I add to that func?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect this `@IBAction` to **both** text fields, for `Editing Changed`:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEdited(_ sender: Any) {

    // reset to disabled every time a text field value changes
    //  will be set to enabled if data is validated
    idCheckButton.isEnabled = false

    // make sure idTextField has text
    guard let idText = idTextField.text, idText != "" else {
        return
    }
    // make sure targetsTextField has text
    guard let targetsText = targetsTextField.text, targetsText != "" else {
        return
    }
    // make sure targetsTextField has only numbers
    guard targetsText.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil else {
        return
    }

    // enable the button
    idCheckButton.isEnabled = true

}
```

This will be called with every character entered in either of the fields. It:

- first resets the button to `.isEnabled = false`
- then checks to see if the id text field has text
- then checks to see if the targets text field has text
- then checks to see that the targets field has only numbers

If it makes it through all 3 checks, it sets the button to `.isEnabled = true`

Comment: It's working, but only if I click another textField once again. For example, I fill first field by String -> button isn't enable, then I fill second field by Int -> button isn't enable, then I just click to first filled field -> button is enable. It isn't in real time. hmmmm...

Comment: @Michael_Gruszka - It sounds like you only added the `@IBAction func textFieldEdited()` connection to your `idTextField` ... you need to make the same connection to your `targetsTextField`

Comment: Yes, I've done it. I connected both fields, and it's working, but function isn't executed by every new letter. Func is executed if you click to another field, or if you hide the keyboard.

Comment: @Michael_Gruszka - double check that you have connected the `Editing Changed` event, not `Value Changed`. Confirm it's correct by adding `print("Editing Changed", sender)` as the first line in the `textFieldEdited()` func. If you do not see that output to the debug console on every new letter, then you have the `@IBAction` connected wrong.

Comment: Ok, got it. I've connected both fields (drag and drop from assistant to storyboard). In my version of xCode func called "textFieldDidChangeSelection" and it is working with first textField, print message every new letter, but doens't work with second textField. I'm sure that both fields are connected :/ If I click "small circle" between lines, next to func, I see both fields connected. However I connect it, it's always working with idTextField- even if just targetsTextField is connected :(

Comment: Ok- it's working. I had to add "[targetsTextField].forEach({ $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChangeSelection(_:)), for: .editingChanged) })" to ViewDidLoad. Thank you so much- You help me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try create a function call `validator()` . all your textField should be add

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // TODO : Validate all of your textField value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String, int: Int) -> Bool {
   let text = (idTextField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
   if text.isEmpty {
      idCheckButton.isEnabled = false
   } else {
      idCheckButton.isEnabled = true
   }

   return true
}
```

Try this

```
// Add these variables
var idValid = false
var targetsValid = false

func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == idTextField {
         // Verify id has text
        if textField.text! != "" {
            idValid = true
        } else {
            idValid = false
        }
    }
    if textField == targetsTextField {
        // Verify targets is numeric
        if textField.text!.isNumeric {
            targetsValid = true
        } else {
            targetsValid = false
        }
    }
    if idValid && targetsValid {
        // Both valid enable
        idCheckButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        // Not both valid disable
        idCheckButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

And you will have to add this extension for String to verify a String as a numeric value - add a new blank Swift file to your project called 'StringExtension' and add:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension String {
    var isNumeric: Bool {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return false }
        let nums: Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        return Set(self).isSubset(of: nums)
    }
}
```